# I have a little problem with Searchlogic in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

For example I have index action:

```
def index
    @search = Product.search(params[:search])
    @products = @search.all
end
```

The instance variable `@search` returns me an Object and when I write a code `@products = @search.all` i get error `undefined method`assert_valid_keys' for #< Class:0x90cbb20>`

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not actually sure Searchlogic works with Rails 3. I think the current gem you want to use is MetaSearch:

https://github.com/ernie/meta_search

I think the syntax is almost exactly the same so anything that you've setup in Searchlogic will carry over to Metasearch.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Searchlogic supports Rails 3.  If you are not tied to it, you can check out the MetaWhere gem as an alternative.  There is a railscasts for it to get you started. [Link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch)